# JMeter won´t start

Tags: java, windows, testing, jmeter

I´m trying to open JMeter but nothing happens, the loading icon appears next to the cursor for one second but nothing happens after that.
I´ve already tried to uninstall java and re install it, I´ve also tried to change the environment variable but nothing seems to work.

The latest version of Java is installed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJsmj.png)

The environment variable for Java is correct:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxNGw.png)

If I try to launch JMeter from the .bat file I get this message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgA7e.png)

It seems like there´s a problem with Java but I can´t fix it, I´ve already tried searching the web for any possible solution but nothing seems to work for me. I don´t really know what else to do
I do not have the skills or knowledge to solve this issue, I would really appreciate if somebody could help me please.

English is not my native language and this is my first post here so I´m sorry if there´s something wrong with the post.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your JMeter installation, the errors you're getting indicate issues with [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

Besides JMeter documentation [suggests using JDK instead of JRE](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#java_versions)

> Although you can use a JRE, it is better to install a JDK as for recording of HTTPS, JMeter needs keytool utility from JDK.

So I would recommend [re-installing JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation) to the folder you have full control in terms of [file permissions](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-ed/000137238/understanding-file-and-folder-permissions-in-windows) (i.e. your [home folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory))

It might also be a good idea to move Java to the folder which path doesn't contain spaces or special characters.

Answer (score -1):

A friend was able to solve this issue for me, if anyone else has this problem just move the JMeter folder to the root folder of your pc (C:).

Comment: Nice that it worked for you. It is not the best way to fix the problem (but an easy way to solve it). Problem is related to environment variables (system path and Java path variables).